# How do I call a c macro from an assembly routine?

Tags: c, assembly, macros

I have a macro `X` that does some stuff like this.

```c
#define X(a,b,c)   \
  a.foo = b;       \
  a.bar = c;
```

I want to call `X` from an assembly routine, like so:

```
.data
pushl $eax;
call X(a, b, c);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: a macro is not a function

Comment: right, but my macro initializes some of the variables passed to it, how do I run this initializing macro from assembly?

Comment: Macros are part of the **C** preprocessor. Assembler is not C. So ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A macro is not a function, which means it does not have an address, thus you can not call it.

Macros are evaluated by the preprocessor. Using them just results in a simple text replacement, as a result they only exist in the source file and nowhere else.

However, what you could do is set up a wrapper function for the macro and call it instead. Like so:

```
#define X(a, b, c) (a).foo = (b); \
    (a).bar = (c)

void _X(struct foo *a, int b, int c)
{
    X(*a, b, c);
}
```

But that just removes the need for a macro in the first place. So you might as well get rid of the macro and use a function.

Comment: I like the ending of the first sentence :-) Note, however, macros are not evaluated **during** compilation, but before (thus **pre**processor) - strictly speaking; how the toolchain actually handles this is a different subject.

Comment: Thanks! This was my initial hunch but your answer clarified the concept alot

Comment: @Alex: Just a well-meant hint: You could have gotten the answer faster by doing some research on your own, e.g in a C book. In general reading - although not modern - is a good way to get additional information which might not be relevant instantly, but you might remember you read about something when you later encounter a similar problem. (really, just a friendly hint)